In C#, can you declare multiple function arguments as a single type?
In Pascal, you can declare multiple function arguments as a single type:
procedure TMyClass.Foo(Bar1, Bar2, Bar3 : string; Bar4, Bar5, Bar6 : Integer);

I always enjoyed this because it prevented needless repetition of type declarations. I know in C#, you can declare multiple variables as a single type:
int foo, bar;

But that doesn't appear to work for C# function arguments:
// Compiler doesn't like this because it expects types for all three arguments
public void Foo(int bar1, bar2, bar3) { }

Does C# have a way to shorthand the declaration of multiple arguments with a single type, or is there some reason it's been rejected? I can't seem to find much information on it, I just keep finding information on multiple-type arguments, which is not what I'm looking for.

No. It looks ugly, sorry.

Are you sure you that you should not be using some higher level type? If Bar1, Bar2, Bar3 are related they should probably have their own type. If they are unrelated it seem weird to use the same type declaration.

I figure you moved from Pascal to C#. If it wasn't your decision: let it go. You're a sharpie now. ;D

If you think you need this presumably recheck your overall coding style. You shouldn't regularly need many parameters in clean code.

Visual Basic got the best compiler: Dim i, j As Integer (here only j becomes integer)

You can also use the params keyword allowing a varying number of parameters to be passed at the call site: public void Foo(params int[] bar) { } or use tuples:  public void Foo((int, int, int) foo, (string, string, string) bar) { }

There's a very good reason this feature has never been added, it leads to buggy code. If you have a function that takes several items of the same type, it's very easy for the caller to get them in the wrong order and there's no compile-time checking. If your function needs a group of things, you should create a record type to hold them. That way they are named when you create the record and you pass a single item of that type to the function, the compiler can tell you if it's the wrong type.

No.
I guess I need more words... "No it doesn't, and is unlikely to ever do so". Reasons: because there hasn't been a compelling enough reason to add it.

It might be worth adding that none of the C-style languages (C, C++, Java) have this. So I'm assuming it isn't in great demand really.

Even VB, which is based off Pascal, doesn't allow this

@Charlieface. Wasn't VB based on Basic (which dates from the early 1960s) and not Pascal (early 1970s). Of course plain old Basic variable naming, declaration and typing were all pretty feeble (uh, basic) back in those days
